# How to translate images with Google Translate in bulk?

Tags: automation, google-translate

My workflow for a single image: I go to https://translate.google.com/, click the "Images" button, click "Browse your computer" to choose an image, translate, download the translated image. This works very well for a single image or a small number of images. However now I have a large number of images (50+).

Can I somehow do this in bulk (in batch)? I am asking specifically about graphical in-place translation, which preserves the layout, where the original text is replaced in the image itself.

(One thing I already tried, instead of using images, use a multipage PDF. But Google Translate does not work for scanned PDFs. However it does work for images.)

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible via https://translate.google.com/. Furthermore, the [Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs) doesn't seem to take images as input. However you could try to stich images together into 1 image:

- [How can I create a collage of over 2000 photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/57146/9282)
- [How do I tile pictures in a grid?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/18373/9282)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is impossible(in the near future perhaps). Someday, someone will build a script to automatically upload, translate and download to google translate, one image at a time.

Answer (score 1):

YES IT'S NOT IMPOSIBLE! BROTHERS I DO IT!
here is a Python code:

import os
from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate

def upload_and_translate(input_dir, output_dir, target_language):
"""Uploads all images in a directory, translates them using Google Translate, and downloads the translated images to a specified output directory.

```
Args:
    input_dir: The directory containing the images to be translated.
    output_dir: The directory to which the translated images will be downloaded.
    target_language: The target language for the translation.
"""

# Create a Google Translate client.
client = translate.Client()

# Get a list of all the files in the input directory.
files = os.listdir(input_dir)

# Iterate over the files and upload them to Google Translate.
for file in files:
    with open(os.path.join(input_dir, file), "rb") as f:
        # Upload the image to Google Translate.
        response = client.translate_image(
            f,
            target_language=target_language,
        )

        # Download the translated image.
        with open(os.path.join(output_dir, file), "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.translated_image)
```

## Example usage:

if **name** == "**main**":
input_dir = "path/to/input/directory"
output_dir = "path/to/output/directory"
target_language = "es"
upload_and_translate(input_dir, output_dir, target_language)

```
If You Don't Know How u Use this Code here is How You can:

To use the provided code, follow these steps:

**Python**:

1. Install the google-cloud-translate library using pip install google-cloud-translate.
2. Save the code as a Python file, for example, upload_and_translate.py.
3. Replace the values of input_dir, output_dir, and target_language with your desired values.
4. Run the script using python upload_and_translate.py.
```